# How can I bind an NSManagedObject to a table/collection view cell using Combine?

Tags: ios, core-data, uikit, combine

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` and a dynamic table view. My table view cells have a text label. How should I bind objects from the fetched results controller to the cell?

In [WWDC 2019 230](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/), there’s a code snippet where a core data object is bound to a view...

```
if let tag = try? fetchRequest.execute().first {
  nameSubscription = tag.publisher(for: \.name).assign(to: \.text, on: tagLabel)
  colorSubscription = tag.publisher(for: \.color).map({ $0 as? UIColor}).assign(to: \.textColor, on: tagLabel)
}
```

Where should this happen in the context of a table view controller with a cell that has a label? Where should the subscriber (`AnyCancellable`) go? Will I need a collection of subscribers since there’s an indefinite number of cells?

Comment: K. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding like this was shown in WWDC session for the detail view, I guess.

Table view cells are being reused during scrolling.

That's why you're not supposed to bind the particular data model's property change to the update of the label in the cell.

Instead, you should observe the changes to the data model on the controller level and reload table view cells and / or sections whenever changes happen.

Comment: Okay. This is what my poorly worded question was trying to get at. So it's not a good idea to bind to cells because they're reused; I should just reload the entire cell as my view controller receives updates.

Comment: But if you use a diffable data source as the video demonstrates you will not need to reload anything.

Comment: Yes, that's another option. I just haven't checked it yet by myself, so can't recommend to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation isn't comparable to the video's situation. The video doesn't perform this kind of binding from a fetched results controller, but rather from a single fetch request; it keeps the display current in case the underlying data changes. As the video goes on to say, the way to keep a table view updated from a fetched results controller is to use the delegate method to derive a snapshot and feed it to a diffable data source.